# Login to webmin with user has no password (SSH)

Tags: 12.04, ssh, amazon-ec2, webmin

I have an simple Ubuntu 12.04 instance running on AWS EC2

I have webmin installed and accessable, but am presented with a login requiring username and password.

As part of the AWS install, you don't have a "root" user you can access, but an "ubuntu" user with sudo rights. This user does not have a password, access is via SSH key pair

I don't want to set a password for ubuntu user, preferring the security of SSH.

How do I access webmin without needing to enter a password? Is it best I create a new userid with a password that is also a sudoer? Seems a bit daft given that is one reason i want webmin in the first place :-)

Answer (score 2):

A slightly updated answer.

Running Ubuntu 20.04 and Webmin 1.99, `changepass.pl` was actually located in `/usr/share/webmin/changepass.pl`.  If yours is not in that location, you can run `sudo find / -name changepass.pl` to find it.

Also, Webmin was setup with username `root` instead of `ubuntu` so the correct command to change the Webmin username was:

`sudo /usr/share/webmin/changepass.pl /etc/webmin root <your_password>`

After running that command I was able to login to the web interface.

Answer (score 1):

I also have that same problem when installing webmin on DigitalOcean Droplet. A bit of research shows me that I can change the password in SSH terminal.

Let's say you want your webmin user `ubuntu` to have password `foo`:
`/usr/libexec/webmin/changepass.pl /etc/webmin ubuntu foo`

Now you can login to webmin with your new password.

Answer (score 0):

The Webmin wiki has a [documentation](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/WebminUsers) section where it explains the process of granting users specific per module or system-wide rights. You will also find examples on how to create new webmin users and how to modify existing user privileges. In effect you can bypass the sudo system but at the same time design a more granular per module per user access control system.